# parent/child mapping for nested categories

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create child/parent mapping  with nested categories, but smohow result is confusing

Firstly I created an index

```
PUT /categories/ {}
```

Then mappings

```
/categories/category/_mappings
{

  "_parent": {"type": "category"}
 }
```

indexes

```
PUT /categories/category/1?parent=0
{
   "name": "Grandparent"

},
PUT /categories/category/2?parent=0
{
   "name": "Grandmother"

}

PUT /categories/category/3?parent=1
{
   "name": "father"

},
PUT /categories/category/4?parent=1
{
   "name": "mother"

}
```

I would then expect that flowing search would return me "Grandparent" category, but it returns me zero hits

```
GET /categories/category/_search
{
"query": {
   "has_child": {
      "type": "category",
      "query" : {
        "filtered": {
          "query": { "match_all": {}}

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first issue here is that the parent  and the child are the same. You are indexing childs in the type category while the parents are the type category. Moreover you are saying the parents is 0 but you did not created it here ( maybe you did earlier). Try to changeyour parent child relation with two different type. i can make a sample code if you want to.

Comment: @Matinator Yeah parent=0 is just an indication that granparnet doesn't have parent  or rather that it is first in a node (i.e. has no parents, I never created them. But elsatcic throws error if I don't include ?parent=X) I tried with different types and that worked fine, but the problem is tehy are not differnet types and it would mean that i would have to index two sets of data?? one for parent categories and one that have no parents?? Is that correct?? It just seemed strange to do such thing. Please do post sample code if that is not a problem? I think I ma seeing this too much as RDBS